# Differentiation in multivariable Calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, definition, partial-derivative

We say that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ if the following are satisfied:

1. The partial derivatives $D_{1} f(x), D_{2} f(x), \cdots, D_{n} f(x)$ exist.
2. There exist $r>0,$ and a real valued function $g$ on $\{\|z\|<r\}$ such
   $$
   \begin{array}{l}
   \text { that } \lim _{\|z\| \rightarrow 0} g(z)=0, \text { and } \\
   \qquad f(x+z)=f(x)+\nabla f(x) \cdot z+\|z\| g(z)
   \end{array}
   $$

I understand that first condition which says partial derivative exist in $n$ directions.

Now for second condition it looks like $1$<sup>st</sup> order Taylor approximation. Can someone explain how it matches with most common definition of multivariable differentiability. How to look at it Geometrically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common definition of derivative of $f$ at $x$ is that it is a linear map $L\colon\Bbb R^n\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ such that$$\lim_{z\to x}\frac{f(z)-f(x)-L(z-x)}{\|z-x\|}=0.\tag1$$So, define$$g(z)=f(z)-f(x)-L(z-x)$$and then $\lim_{z\to x}g(z)=0$. On the other hand, the only linear map for which $(1)$ can possibly hold is the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}\Bbb R^n&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\z&\mapsto&\nabla f(x)\cdot z.\end{array}$$

Comment: L is linear approximation using tangent plane right ?

Comment: No. The map $L$ is the [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) of of at the point $x$.

Comment: Can you explain this defination using this definition ?

Comment: Given a function $f: D \subset \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and an interior point $\left(x_{0}, y_{0}\right)$ in $D,$ let $L$ be the plane given by
$$
L(x, y)=f_{x}\left(x_{0}, y_{0}\right)\left(x-x_{0}\right)+f_{y}\left(x_{0}, y_{0}\right)\left(y-y_{0}\right)+f\left(x_{0}, y_{0}\right)
$$
The function $f$ is called differentiable at $\left(x_{0}, y_{0}\right)$ iff the function $f$ is approximated by the plane $L$ near $\left(x_{0}, y_{0}\right),$ that is,
$$
f(x, y)=L(x, y)+\epsilon_{1}\left(x-x_{0}\right)+\epsilon_{2}\left(y-y_{0}\right)
$$

Comment: where the functions $\epsilon_{1}$ and $\epsilon_{2} \rightarrow 0$ as $(x, y) \rightarrow\left(x_{0}, y_{0}\right)$
The function $f$ is differentiable iff $f$ is differentiable at every interior point of $D$.

Comment: If that's how you define differentiable function, then that definition and the one from my previous comment are the same ones.

Comment: So L is linear approximation right ?

Comment: The map $L$ is, *by definition*, the derivative of $f$ at $x$. Yes, it is also the best linear approximation of $f-f(x)$ near $x$.

Comment: Also can you explain how to look this definition geometrically ? Given in question.

Comment: So to be precise 1) condition ensure partial derivative exist in all n axis directions

Comment: But to ensure derivative exist partial derivative must exist in all directions , so how second condition give the existence in all directions ?

Comment: Let $L(z)=\nabla f(x)\cdot z$. Then given any direction $v$, you have$$0=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|f(x+hv)-f(x)-L(x+hv-x)|}{\|x+hv-x\|}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|f(x+hv)-f(x)-hL(v)|}{|h|\|v\|}.$$Therefore, the directional derivative in the direction given by $v$ exists and it is equal to $L(v)$, since$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+hv)-f(x)}h=L(v).$$

Comment: Also definition given in question has norm z going to 0 but in your definition it is going to x  please explain that part as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120846/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-maths-student).